# Is it possible to uniquely identify DOM elements in React code?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, dom

I am using React Dev Tools to inspect a React App in Chrome. Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: react_dev_tools]

Now **I would like to identify the highlighted input object in my React code**, in order to modify the event that is called when I type in some input. My problem is that there are several input elements in the DOM. I can easily type in some random number in one of the input fields and then identify which element in the DOM I have modified by my input. But I do not know how to identify that element in the code since there are several input elements of the same type in the code. That makes it hard to identify the specific line or the specific element in the code that I modified in the DOM.

Is there a way to find a specific DOM element in the code? Or to modify my code such that I find out which element in the code has called the event handler?

I have tried to log `this` in the console in the event handler but `this` in my case returns a reference to the entire component and not the specific element that called the event handler.

Comment: You can use findDOMnode on `this` component instance, at least for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but `findDOMNode` on `this` returns an html tree of the entire component and not just one specific element. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: findDOMNode(componentInstance) returns DOM element that corresponds to this instance (if any). If there's no correspondence (like <input> in your case that corresponds to no component), you won't able to do that. Debuggability is one of several reasons to use components at many levels.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

As the main image of [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) shows, you can inspect the element on the screen and see the structure of the code. This will be a helpfull tool for you.
If you want to know exactly what field to change, just add so prop to the field like `id='123'` and you will be able to see it in the Dev Tools.
To learn how to install and use that Chrome plugin, you can do a little search and you will find it ;)

[image: react-dev-tools]

**Edit:** I said to add a prop field like `id='123'` but you can add any prop like `elementIWantToSee='here'`and with the Dev Tools you would easily find the element

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have installed the React Dev Tools to Chrome and I have edited my original question as I am still having problems to identify a DOM element in the code, since there are several elements of the same type with the same id. I have added a screenshot of what I see in the React Dev Tools to my original question. 

Is there still a way to identify the element that has called the event handler?

Comment: @Dom *there are several elements of the same type with the same id* - this is a mistake, for starters. Id attributes are supposed to be unique.